# How lock keyword in open function in julia is used?

Tags: multithreading, julia

The `open(filename::AbstractString; lock = true, keywords...)` function has a keyword lock. According to official documentation **"The lock keyword argument controls whether operations will be locked for safe multi-threaded access."** Even after putting lock keyword to true explicitly, I can open the same file in different a process(for testing I used 2 julia REPLs) and edit it from both process. Now, my questions are:

1. What does lock keyword actually do?
2. Is there any way to open a file exclusively in a process and make other processes wait for it to prevent data race?
3. Even after `lock=true`, can the file get corrupted if two processes try to write it at the same time?
4. What does **"safe multi-threaded access"** mean in this context?

I am using Julia 1.7.3 on linuxmint 20.3

Comment: For the quick reference of people who might stumble upon this in the future: [here is the Discourse thread](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/what-does-lock-keyword-in-open-function/86170/) discussing this question and its solutions.